# Send Periodically updates to server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

What is the best practice for send periodically updates (ex: about Trip price) to server? What should I using for that? How I should organize this updates (tasks)? What type of tasks I should using for that? I should using periodically tasks for that (this task will send update to server)?

Answer (score 0):

Check NSURLRequest and NSURLConnection classes.

```
NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30.0]; 
NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

There is also helpful guide
[URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is a really big and subjective question, and depends very much on the fundamentals of how your client and server is designed and what you're trying to do.

But I will take a stab at an official answer:

The two standard ways I've seen for updating a server are either

***1)***

HTTP requests with parameters calling back into the server (e.g. "http : // www.yourservice.com/something.php?tripprice=2500")

This is pretty much what @beryllium just said.  :-)

or

***2)***

POST requests with some kind of JSON or XML payload.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a webservice which will take parameters from program which you want to update and on server side a script will continuously run and will check updateds and update data accordingly. You need to call this webservice after particular time interval and continuously.